# Add canonical tag in <head> tag if not existing using PHP

Tags: php, canonical-link

What I want is add canonical tag inside the `<head>` tag if canonical tag does not exist using PHP

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
function addtag(){     
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
    $link = $doc->createElement('link');
    $newLink = $body->appendChild($link);
    $newLink->setAttribute("canonical", 'http://');
    //$linkText = $doc->createTextNode("Display Text For Link");
    //$newLink->appendChild($linkText);


    echo $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: what is failing? any error message?

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://localhost/onlineshopping/test/test1.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in C:\wamp\www\onlineshopping\test\config.php on line 6

Comment: what is in config,php on line 6? Show us some code

Comment: This is the code inside the config.php

Comment: you mean the above code from your question is the code in C:\wamp\www\onlineshopping\test\config.php ?

Comment: yes i think its better to forget my code and think about new solution to do the task